# How to obtain documentation on functions inside some of the packages that are automatically loaded by Mathematica?

Tags: packages, undocumented

Mathematica comes with lots of useful functions which seems not to be documented. At least I do not know how to find the API documentation to learn more about these functions and how to use them.

```
Quit[]
$Packages
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For an example, picking one package above

```
?SystemTools`*
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However to use these, typing

```
?? SystemTools`FileJoin
```

There is no documentation. Clicking on name shows only the following

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems many could be useful to learn about what they do. The same for any other

```
?Security`*
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Are these not supposed to be documented and are therefore not supposed to be used by users?

V 13.2.1

Comment: does this give something close to what you need: ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[SystemTools`FileJoin]``?

Comment: @kglr oh yes, I forgot about `PrintDefinitions`. Yes this help, but it is not the same as having documentation explaining with examples how to use these functions as one have to read the code and reverse engineer what it is used for. But better than nothing. I assume then, these functions are not meant to be used by users. Like the Internal functions: $\text{Names["Internal`*"]}$ which is also hard to get documentation on.

Comment: Documentation is basically a contract between us (WRI) and the userbase.  If is not documented, then we are not willing to go on the record.  You can experiment with them, use them to your hearts content.  If they change/break...  well...  you were warned.